Why do I keep getting TypeError: Class constructor IndexedDBLocalPersistence cannot be invoked without 'new' when using flutter 3.22.2 & dart 3.4.3
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:web/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web/authentication/login_screen.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
   );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.setPersistence(Persistence.NONE);

  }
  catch (e) {
    print('Error initializing Firebase: $e');
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Task Management Admin Portal',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Roboto', // Ensure to use the font family
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(primary: Colors.deepPurple),
        // Adjust color scheme as needed
        // useMaterial3: true, // Remove this as it's currently not supported
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}

The code be able to log in successfully in the web app without getting the error and lead me to the home screen.
I am using flutter the framework for dart programming language and firebase for my backend.
